# i am trying to create a update trigger

Tags: plsql

I'm currently creating some sort of inventory system.

I have table stu_marks where in I save the marks.

stu_marks:

```
roll_no   english  hindi
1          65       84
2          83       76
3          73       54
```

I also have the table total_marks where in I save total_marks for each student.

total_marks

```
roll_no      tot_marks
1              149
2              159
3              127
```

my problem is how i update total_marks simultaneously whenever i update marks in any subject in stu_marks?

Answer (score 0):

You want a view, not a table.

```
CREATE VIEW total_marks AS
  SELECT roll_no, english + hindi AS tot_marks
    FROM stu_marks;
```

Now `total_marks` will always have the data you want from `stu_marks`.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but this is how you will go for a `AFTER UPDATE` trigger. So, whenever you update a marks in stu_marks table total marks will get recalculated accordingly

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_total_marks
AFTER UPDATE
   ON stu_marks
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

UPDATE total_marks
SET tot_marks = :new.english + :new.hindi
WHERE roll_no = :new.roll_no;

END;
```

Comment: sir its not working its shows a error. this trigger is created with compilation error and when i try to update stu_marks table it does not update stu_marks table.

Comment: @user1984635, do you mind to sharing the actual error statement as well. That will help me; cause I just can't keep guessing in dark ... right?

Comment: sir, it created with compilation error and i whenever i tried to update stu_marks table then it show error ORA-04098: trigger 'DEEP.UPDATE_TOTAL_MARKS' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: @user1984635, don't just say thanks. accept the answer by clicking the check button to show your appreciation.